# How to read input in python using raw_input

Tags: python, input, raw-input

```
Sample Input (in Plaintext) 
1 
1 2
```

Description- The first line contains an integer t, denoting the number of test cases. Next t lines contain two integers, a and b separated by a space.

My question is how can I load these inputs into variables using Python 2.7? Also I need to load this into IDE without using "xxx.py > input.txt"

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Did you search the documentation for reading from file?

Comment: This should be language dependent, I think so. Not IDE dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raw_input() takes in a line of input as a string. The .split() string method produces a list of the whitespace-separated words in a string. int() parses a string as an int. So putting that together, you can read the input you want using

```
t = int(raw_input())
cases = []
for i in range(t):
    cases.append( map(int, raw_input().split()) )
```

This will give you a list of a,b pairs if the input is in the correct format, but won't do any error checking.